# Regex to validate user input

Tags: javascript, regex

I need regex to accept following input

input can be any one

```
*
between 0 to 59
0-59/3
0-59(range)
*/3(step)
1-3,5(range)
```

because I am getting input from user to set up cron job
I need to get valid input sec,min hours, days, weekofday from user

Comment: give your sample input output and show some effort .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You need to use regex, than this is close:

```
^([1-5]?\d|\*(\/[1-5]?\d)?|[1-5]?\d-[1-5]?\d(\/[1-5]?\d|,[1-5]?\d)?)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/bB3iW7/2

But this will not check if given ranges are proper, i.e. it will acccept ranges like: `9-1` or `10-10, 3`

Don't think this could be easily accomplished with regex.

In the other hand, it can be enough for js validation.